# number of combinations that each item has been exists at lease once with repetition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Suppose there exists 3 letters and it is required to choose 4 letter from them (repetition is allowed). This 3 letters should be selected at least once and the order is important.

An example suppose we have letter a,b,c
we can have:
abca
abcb
abcc
cbaa
bacc
and 
so on.

What is the formula for this example?
what is the general formula when we have n letter and combination with length r?

Comment: For your general question, the answer will be $n!S(r,n)$, where $S(r,n)$ is a Stirling Number of the Second Kind (please see Wikipedia, or some of the many MSE answers that mention Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind).    For very small numbers, careful enumeration will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is equivalent to find the number of surjections $Sur(r,n)$ from the set $ 
\left\{ {1,\, \cdots ,r} \right\}$ onto the set $ \left\{ {1,\, \cdots ,n} \right\}$. Clearly we have the recurrence $Sur(r,n)=n(Sur(r-1,n)+Sur(r-1,n-1))$, with $Sur(0,0)=1$. Which results in $Sur(r,n) = n!\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  r \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\}$ as indicated in the comment by André Nicolas.

Comment: @G Cab Thank you very much for the answer. when we have 4 letters and we want to build 7 length combination, by enumeration we have 10920. however if we use the formula you provided we have 4!*{4 7}  that is another number. I got really confused. can you please explain it more.

Comment: @SSD my computation for the case of words from the alphabet {a,b,c,d}, of length 7 characters, and that contain ** at least one occurrence of each character ** gives 8400, which corresponds to the formula.